# lost original log in details

Tags: support

I recently cleaned my pc of cookies etc.   Now I find that I cant log in to Stack Overflow as I have been doing for some months.   I had to create an id to be able to post this question but that does not give me access to the account I have been using on Stack Overflow.  Is there any way I can get back to my original account?

Comment: What is your original account?

Comment: I dont understand your question.  I had a name 'Ron Etherington' and a login but I cant find the password for that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you provided us a valid email address, use the account recovery link on the login page.